# How do I run an Intern against Appium / iOS simulator?

Tags: intern

According to https://saucelabs.com/docs/platforms/appium, I should be able to run against the Appium iOS simulator (as opposed to the old Selenium RC iOS simulator) with:

```
caps = {browserName: ''};
caps.platform = 'OS X 10.8';
caps.version = '7';
caps['device-orientation'] = 'portrait';
caps.app = 'safari' or 'URL-TO-YOUR-APP';
caps.device = 'iPhone Simulator';
```

However, it's not working for me (with app specified as "safari").  Is there another configuration that will work?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 Appium is currently broken. If you watch the video log you will see there is a window obscured behind the iOS Simulator. That window is showing an error message that says iOS Simulator failed to install an application, and Safari never starts. Using version '6.1' instead of '7' works. Presumably 7 will work again shortly. Note that you must make sure 'selenium-version' is blank for Appium to be used; you can tell in the metadata for the run whether or not it is using Appium because the word appium will be in the 'selenium version' field.